# How to make swirled edge circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to make a swirled edge circle like this for a logo in illustrator. What would be the best method to use?
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It's not 1 circle. it's multiple circles/ellipses.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are not going to copy an existing logo, but need a little resembling circle

[image]

1. Draw a circle with no fill. Delete a part of the line.
2. Make rotated and moved copies. You can also draw some different curves like in your example.
3. Make width variations  with the width tool or apply an art brush. Your own example has complex profiles which need art brushes.

Have color variations to make the turns distinguishable. I have only 3 different grays, but there's no limit how rich colors are possible. You may need to expand the strokes to filled areas to apply complex effects.

Custom art brushes can be made easily. In the next image in the left there's 3 partial circles like above and the applied (simple) art brushes are shown in the right.

[image]

Comment: thank you! That is very helpful!